# Facebook Graph API Search - Search for Groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Its my First Question in Stack-overflow Community, I wish that i will get good response from all of you.

I was trying to work on Facebook Graph API to search for groups using below URL ......

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=programming&type=group
```

According to new Documentation, it needs an access token, But I did not found any suitable Link from where i can get Facebook Groups Access Token.

Kindly help me to get the access token with some efficient procedure and Refined the above URL with access_token.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just needs *an* access token, not specifically a group access token. append a user access token to the end of your query and it will work.

eg `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=programming&type=group&access_token=USERACCESSTOKEN` returns

```
{
data: [
{
name: "Programmers,Developers",
privacy: "CLOSED",
id: "361338743928370"
},
{
name: "I am Programmer,I have no life.",
privacy: "OPEN",
id: "1840883746179186"
},
{
name: "Pojok Programmer",
privacy: "OPEN",
id: "444794115578165"
},
{
name: "Fitness Programming By CVG",
privacy: "CLOSED",
id: "416198445414413"
},
{
name: "freeCodeCamp Earth",
privacy: "OPEN",
id: "321090721625587"
},
{
name: "Learn Programming Basics and Latest Tricks ✪",
privacy: "CLOSED",
id: "320779011722495"
},
{
name: "Python Programming Language",
privacy: "OPEN",
id: "457660044251817"
}]}
```

You can retrieve a token for testing using the access token tool https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

Comment: Sorry to revive - could you please confirm that this doesn't work anymore, because Search has been restricted since then?